# how to trigger an alert on state change

Tags: reactjs

I am passing a variable data that is subjected to change from a child component. In the parent component, I am receiving the variable data like this:

```
<ChildComponent sendDataToParent={sendDataToParent}/>;

let passedVal;
const sendDataToParent = (val) => {
    passedVal = val;
};
```

So I want an alert to be triggered anytime the passed variable changes.
So I bind the passed data to a state, and then use useEffect hook. But the useEffect does not trigger anytime the passedValue changes. Though if click the button it shows the changed passed data.

```
export default function ParentComponet() {
    const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(passedVal);

    const showPassedData = () => {  // This triggers on click of a button
        setIsSelected(passedVal);
        alert(passedVal)
    };

    useEffect(() => {  // It does not trigger after passedVal changes
        setIsSelected(passedVal);
        alert(passedVal)
    }, [passedVal])

    return (
        <div>
            <Button
                onClick={showPassedData}
            >
                Show Passed Data
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That does not work because React can't detect changes of a normal variable using `useEffect`. It can only detect state/props changes. In your case `passedVal` is just a variable, even if you change it, it will not trigger `useEffect`.

So instead of this

```
let passedVal;
const sendDataToParent = (val) => { 
  passedVal = val;
};
```

you can do this:

```
const [passedVal, setPassedVal] = useState();
<ChildComponent sendDataToParent={setPassedVal}/>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Why I can't use useState is because the passed data is declared outside the react function because there are dependencies, and it is not possible to use a hook outside a react function.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your implementation, you could consider refactoring to store it inside React state or context if you want to consume it it various places in your application. Because React architecture is based on state/props to detect and update your components.

Answer (score 0):

`sendDataToParent` does not really send data to parent component. If you want to do that you'd need to use smth like Redux or React's context. It's a bit hard to see the complete structure of your components from the code you provided but I think an easier way would be to pass a callback from the parent component to the child, that will be invoked when value changes.

```
export default function ParentComponent() {
    const onDataChange = (val) => {
        alert(val)
    }

    return (
        // ...
        <ChildComponent onDataChange={onDataChange}/>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your example above is how I passed the data from the child to the parent